# How to read Last Modified Date in a file on S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, metadata, datecreated

i want to read last modified or created date in a s3 file. i have seen the coding to list all files but i wanted to find a specific file's modified date.

i used this coding to retrive the s3 file

```
S3Object s3ProfileObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(srcBucket, fullProfilePath));

InputStream profileData = s3ProfileObject.getObjectContent();

SONObject rawProfileObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse( new InputStreamReader(profileData, "UTF-8"));
```

is it possible to read it using `s3ProfileObject` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `S3ObjectSummary` for that. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectSummary.html#getLastModified--) is the documentation for it. Below is the sample code (from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html)):

```
final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
ListObjectsV2Result result = s3.listObjectsV2(bucket_name);
List<S3ObjectSummary> objects = result.getObjectSummaries();
for (S3ObjectSummary os: objects) {
    System.out.println("* " + os.getKey());
}
```

From `S3ObjectSummary`, you can make another request and get `S3Object`.

If you want to include a specific file or files with specific prefix then you can use `` object with `withPrefix` method along with the request, e.g.:

```
ListObjectsV2Request listObjectsV2Request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
    .withBucketName("test-bucket")
    .withPrefix("file-prefix");
```

ListObjectsV2Result result = s3client.listObjectsV2(listObjectsV2Request);

[Here's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsV2Request.html) the javadoc for `ListObjectsV2Request`.

Comment: the problem is it run all the files in the bucket ( all the folders ). i have a file called abc in the directory of test  i need to check only that file. how can i do it ? cause this gives 

test/abc.json
test2/abc.json